# Передача данных между несколькими контроллерами

Tags: ios

[image: Контроллеры]
Левый красный контроллер - главный.

От него получается передать данные на другой красный контроллер.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let firstVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GroupsViewController") as! GroupsViewController

    firstVC.name = nameGroupArray[indexPath.row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
}
```

Делаю по аналогии и с синими контроллерами, но перейти из левого синего на правый синий контроллер не получается:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController

    secondVC.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]!
    secondVC.name = nameArray[indexPath.row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)}
```

Данные в обоих левых контроллерах - collectionViewCell (если это важно).

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Вот здесь и ошибка. По теме вопроса вы все делаете правильно, исправите ошибку – все будет работать.

Comment: а как ее исправить?))

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, открывайте новый

Comment: Вылечил переименованием всех лейблов в синих контроллерах. Плюс были одинаковые переменные с красным контроллером. Спасибо за помощь.